# ssh cannot resolve hostname (working on WSL but not on CMD or Powershell)

Tags: powershell, ssh, cmd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to connect to my raspberry pi over SSH. Using WSL, everything works as expected however, if I try using CMD or Powershell, I get the error `ssh: Could not resolve hostname`

What could be causing this problem?

Edit: Using the IP address works on CMD and Powershell. Using the hostname used to work yesterday.

Comment: What is the result of using an `nslookup.exe` command?

Comment: CMD and Powershell would use a separate resolver from WSL, is your PI's hostname in: 
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.
Can confirm further why WSL is working if the PI's hostname is in: /etc/hosts. Or if have a separate resolver configuration file checking there